# How to remove lines in CSV file enclosed in DOUBLE Quotes Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, txt

I am new to Python and I am having trouble with a CSV file. I have a sample CSV file containing data like this:

```
"123,hahaha,,,"
"345,hohoho,,,"
```

When I use `read_csv`, the output treats each line as the first column. I need the output to be:

```
123,hahaha,,,
345,hohoho,,,
```

Each line should be treated as a separate column. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

First reformat the file: remove the starting double quote, the ending newline and the ending double quotes using the code below:

```
# Assuming your csv file is named 'file.csv' and is in the same directory that this code is running
with open ("formatted_file.csv", "w") as formatted_file:
    with open ("file.csv", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            formatted_line = line.rstrip()[1:-1] + "\n"
            formatted_file.write(formatted_line)
```

Then use the newly created file.
To check wether it is ok, you can read it as below:

```
with open ("formatted_file.csv", "r") as formatted_file:
    for line in formatted_file:
        print(line, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
df = (
    pd.read_csv("file.csv", header=None, quoting=3) # QUOTE_NONE
        .replace('"', "", regex=True).iloc[:, :-1]
         # .set_axis(["col1", ...]) # optional
)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

     0       1   2   3
0  123  hahaha NaN NaN
1  345  hohoho NaN NaN
```